# Xamarin - Custom Frame Renderer shadow not changing

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

I'm trying to customize the ListView elements shadow effect for both iOS and Android, but everything I try takes no effect.

Here is my DataTemplate used in the ListView:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="greenProductTemplate">
                <ViewCell>
                    <customcontrols:CustomFrame
                        Margin="10"
                        Padding="10"
                        CornerRadius="6">
```

And this is my Custom Renderer:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Frame), typeof(CustomFrameRenderer))]
namespace Prods.iOS
{
    class CustomFrameRenderer: FrameRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Frame> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Element != null)
            {
                if (Element.HasShadow)
                {
                    this.Layer.ShadowRadius = 2.0f;
                    this.Layer.ShadowColor = UIColor.Gray.CGColor;
                    this.Layer.ShadowOffset = new CGSize(2, 2);
                    this.Layer.ShadowOpacity = 0.20f;
                    this.Layer.ShadowPath = UIBezierPath.FromRect(Layer.Bounds).CGPath;
                    this.Layer.MasksToBounds = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I change the render in a number of ways, everything that I could find online, but nothing changes the initial shadow.

Comment: Could it work ?

Comment: I ended up using an third party library because nothing seemed to work. https://redcorners.com/forms/

Answer (score 3):

Try to update your XF version to the latest,and change your shadow in `Draw` method.

**ios:**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Frame), typeof(CustomFrameRenderer))]
namespace Prods.iOS   
{
  class CustomFrameRenderer : FrameRenderer
  {
 
    public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
    {
        base.Draw(rect);
        base.LayoutSubviews();
        this.Layer.ShadowRadius = 2.0f;
        this.Layer.ShadowColor = UIColor.Red.CGColor;
        this.Layer.ShadowOffset = new CGSize(2, 2);
        this.Layer.ShadowOpacity = 1.0f;
        this.Layer.ShadowPath = UIBezierPath.FromRect(Layer.Bounds).CGPath;
        this.Layer.MasksToBounds = false;
    }
  }
}
```

effect like:

[image]

**Update** :

**Android**:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Frame), typeof(CustomFrameRenderer))]
namespace Prods.Droid
{
  public class CustomFrameRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.FrameRenderer
  {
     public CustomFrameRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
     {
     }

     protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Frame> e)
     {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement.HasShadow)
        {
            SetOutlineSpotShadowColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Red);
            Elevation = 10.0f;
            TranslationZ = 10.0f;
           
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add render for android too? I found that Droid shadow is always hard to do.

Comment: @VisualSharp Android shadow is something like the update above.